# How to rewrite to a different domain using rack-rewrite?

Tags: ruby, url-rewriting, rack-rewrite

I want to make a rewrite to another domain so that http://domain1.com/abc would point to http://domain2.com/xyz. This is my code:

```
require 'rack/rewrite'
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Rewrite) do
  rewrite '/abc', 'http://domain2.com/xyz'
end
```

But after I open http://domain1.com/abc, Im being pointed to  http://domain1.com/http:/domain2.com/xyz . How could I rewrite it so that it would point to the right place?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a redirect for this, not a rewrite. Rewrites just change the URL that your app sees whilst redirects do an actual HTTP 301.

```
require 'rack/rewrite'
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Rewrite) do
  r301 '/abc', 'http://domain2.com/xyz'
end
```